# Limit using L'Hopital's Rule.

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\left( \frac{\alpha(1-x^\beta )-\beta(1-x^\alpha)}{(1-x^\beta)(1-x^\alpha)}\right)$$

$\color{red}{\alpha\cdot\beta\ne0}$

Hello! 
Here are faced with a problem. I can not solve this example. After applying the obtained uncertainty. What to do next, I do not know. We have to somehow deal with $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Define $$u(x)=\alpha  \left(1-x^{\beta }\right)-\beta  \left(1-x^{\alpha }\right)$$ $$v(x)=\left(1-x^{\alpha }\right) \left(1-x^{\beta }\right)$$ and apply L'Hopital's rule since the ratio is $\frac 00$.

Doing it once, you have, after some basic simplifications, $$u'(x)=\frac{\alpha  \beta  \left(x^{\alpha }-x^{\beta }\right)}{x}$$ $$v'(x)=\frac{(\alpha +\beta ) x^{\alpha +\beta }-\beta  x^{\beta }-\alpha  x^{\alpha }}{x}$$ that is to say $$\frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}=\frac{\alpha  \beta  \left(x^{\alpha }-x^{\beta }\right)}{(\alpha +\beta ) x^{\alpha
   +\beta }-\beta  x^{\beta }-\alpha  x^{\alpha }}$$ which is still $\frac 00$.

Apply L'Hopital's rule once more and I bet that you will get the result which is very simple.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: That's what happens:
$$\frac{u''(x)}{v''(x)}=\frac{\alpha  \beta\frac{1}{x}  \left(x^{\alpha }-x^{\beta }\right)}{(\alpha +\beta )^2 x^{\alpha +\beta-1 }-\beta^2  x^{\beta-1 }-\alpha^2  x^{\alpha-1 }}$$

Comment: still turns uncertainty

Comment: No, what you posted in comments is not correct.! Recompute the derivative of the numerator and denominator for my last expression  to get the proper $\frac{u''(x)}{v''(x)}$

Comment: I did so. After the resulting wrote.

Comment: For the numerator, it is not correct. I suppose it should be $\alpha  \beta  \left(\alpha  x^{\alpha -1}-\beta  x^{\beta -1}\right)$

Comment: Yes, of course. I ordered the brackets $x$.

Comment: @andre1. Don't forget to simplify ! The result is **very** simple.

Comment: I do not see the result. Could you another answer to the end of write?

Comment: What are the values of the last numerator and denominator when $x=1$ ?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{\alpha  \beta  \left(\alpha 1^{\alpha-1 }-\beta 1^{\beta-1 }\right)}{(\alpha +\beta )^2 1^{\alpha
   +\beta-1 }-\beta^2  1^{\beta-1 }-\alpha^2  1^{\alpha-1 }} \right)$$

Comment: If I remember $1^z=1$. Your turn now.

Comment: This will be carried out correctly and in our case?

Comment: In the expression, make $x=1$ and $x^z=1$ to check if you still have $\frac 00$.

Comment: You are very welcome ! By the way, just as abel showed, it is infinitely easier using Taylor.

Answer (score 1):

i will do a change of variable $$x = 1 + h, x^\alpha = (1 + h)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha h + \frac 1 2 \alpha(\alpha - 1)h^2 + \cdots$$  that gives 
$$1 - x^\alpha =  -\alpha h - \frac 1 2 \alpha(\alpha - 1)h^2 + \cdots\\
\alpha (1-x^\beta) -\beta(1- x^\alpha) =   - \frac 1 2 \alpha\beta [(\beta - 1) - (\alpha - 1)]h^2 + \cdots\\
(1 - x^\alpha)(1 - x^\beta) =  \alpha \beta h^2  + \cdots\\
\frac{\alpha (1 - x^\beta) - \beta(1 - x^\alpha)}{(1 - x^\alpha)(1 - x^\beta)}=\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}+ \cdots
 $$

Comment: Too easy using Taylor (I love Taylor) !! The OP asked for L'Hopital. Cheers :-)